# Macros not running from VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, macros

I have a macro, which replaces the HTML body of the email template. I'm trying to run that Macro from VF Page, but it seems to be not running. When I directly run the macro then it's working fine.

Here is my VF Page:

```
<apex:page >
    <A HREF="#" onClick="openInWidget('0JZ3O00000000TwWAI');return false">Click here to select a macro</A>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/52.0/integration.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openInWidget(id) {
            sforce.console.selectMacro(id);
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Any errors you get on screen?

Comment: No, I’m not getting any error

Comment: Can you open your browser console and see if anything that fails?

Comment: I checked that, and there is no error